# Value stored in accessor method used in a for loop?

Tags: java, object, for-loop, accessor

Essentially, I need to use the value from the getOriginalPrice method in a module.

When I simply put item.getOriginalPrice * .1, my code still compiles.

Not sure whats going on with this one.

Here is my code (not pasting the original class code unless needed).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class InventoryApp {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String invNum = " ";
   double ogPrice = 1;
   int finishItems;

   Inventory saleItem;
   saleItem = new Inventory();

   Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Input the item numbers and original price for each item");

   System.out.println("and I will show you the discounted price of each item");

   System.out.println("for each day of the sale this week.");

   System.out.println("Enter stop at the first prompt to end your list.");


   System.out.println("Enter the item number of the item (Ex. 2b)");
   invNum = keyb.next();
   saleItem.setItemNumber(invNum);
   while (!invNum.equals("stop")) {

   System.out.println("Enter the item's original price (Ex 23.50");
   ogPrice = keyb.nextDouble();
   saleItem.setOriginalPrice(ogPrice);
   printSaleData(saleItem);

   System.out.println("Enter the item's item number");
   invNum = keyb.next();
   saleItem.setItemNumber(invNum);



   }//end While




   }//end main
   public static void printSaleData(Inventory item) {

   System.out.println("Item Number: " + item.getItemNumber());

      for(int x = 1; x < 7; x = x + 1) {
         item.getOriginalPrice() = item.getOriginalPrice - 
(item.getOriginalPrice * .1);
         System.out.println("Day: " + x + "\t" + "Price: $" + item.getOriginalPrice());

      }//end for
   }
}//end Class
```

Comment: What do you think `item.getOriginalPrice() = ...` does?

Comment: `item.getOriginalPrice()` is a getter, you can not set value like this `item.getOriginalPrice() = item.getOriginalPrice - 
(item.getOriginalPrice * .1);`

Comment: Well I know that item.getOriginalPrice pulls the value assigned to my private attribute (originalPrice) so I kind of figured it could be used in place of a variable of some sorts?

Comment: Could I potentially declare a new variable within that module as a placeholder for the value I'd get from the accessor and use that instead?

Comment: You need to set value to your private then using the setter, not the getter

Comment: annnd I just answered my own question, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your printSaleDate method is not valid java. From your posted info, it's not clear what's your expected output.

But strictly speaking this is your posted method once fixed:

```
for (int x=1; x<7; x++) {
    double discountedPrice = item.getOriginalPrice() * 0.1;
    System.out.println("Day: " + x + "\tPrice: $" + discountedPrice);
}
```